# Generators of $O_8^+(2):\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I am trying to find out what the generators of $O_8^+(2):\mathbb Z_2$ are, and they are given in the [ATLAS of Finite Group Representations](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/group/O8p2/#sgens). However I do not understand the explanation given:

> Standard generators of O8+(2):2 are c, d where c is in class 2F, d is in class 10BC and cd has order 18. Alternatively: c is in class 2F, d has order 10, cd has order 18 and cdd has order 30.

What does class 2F and 10BC mean? Under "presentation" section, stuff are crossed out.

So the question is what are the generators and what are the complete set of relations they must satisfy to generate this group.

(Bonus question, is this group related to the Weyl group of $E_8$? I've read that the orientation preserving subgroup of $W(E_8)$ is a $\mathbb Z_2$ extension of $O_8^+(2)$.)

Comment: The notation 2F, etc, is for conjugacy classes as specified in the character tables in the printed ATLAS. I expect the crossed out relations in the presentation are redundant.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I need to take a look at the printed version then, thanks a lot! After asking I realized that the page has a magma code for the group, and in the code it is indeed written that those generators are redundant. But I somehow failed to make magna or gap generate the group and confirm the order, with those relations. I'm not sure whether it's an issue of wrong relations or lack of enough computational resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Magma script uses the alternative description of $c$  and $d$ to find them. From the ATLAS, we know that $c$ lies outside of $O_8^+(2)$ and has centralizer in $O_8^+(2)$ of order 1451520. That's enough to locate it from a list of conjugacy class representatives.

```
> G:=SOPlus(8,2);
> C:=Classes(G);
> C2 := [c : c in C | 
         c[1] eq 2 and not c[3] in DerivedGroup(G)];
> #C2;
2
> [#Centraliser(G,c[3]) : c in C2];
[ 2903040, 9216 ]
> c := C2[1][3]; //in class 2F
> repeat
  repeat> repeat d:=Random(G); od := Order(d);
          until od mod 10 eq 0;
  repeat> d := d^(od div 10);  //now d has order 10
  repeat> until Order(c*d) eq 18 and Order(c*d*d) eq 30;
> Order(c), Order(d), Order(c*d), Order(c*d*d);
2 10 18 30
> sub< G | c,d> eq G;
true
> c,d;
[1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1]
[0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]

[1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1]
[1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really great! As a physicist, I only recently discovered GAP and Magma and it has opened up a whole new world of possibilities for me. Just a last question, is it possible to construct $O_8^+(2)$ in gap as well (the equivalent of SOPlus(8,2) function)? I can't seem to find out how in the documentation. Would like to repeat the same calculation there as well.

Comment: Yes, you can define the group in GAP with $\mathtt{SpecialOrthogonalGroup}(1,8,2)$. You can certainly do the same calculation in GAP, but I am slightly more familiar with Magma, which is why I used that.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much. This was very helpful.